# SQL Server / Oracle : insert value from a select statement for an non-identity column (Insert into…values((select statement), value1, value2, value3)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert (`user_id`) value from a select statement like below. It works, but `user_id` doesn't get increased since `user_id` is not an identity column. I want to increase `user_id` count on every insert query run. Right now it's not happening. I created a db fiddle. I want this code to work on both SQL Server and Oracle versions.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=ba954e4d37831a46aea3b3f3b499cc51

```
CREATE TABLE b_user (
  user_id      INT,
  user_name    VARCHAR(250),
  user_email   VARCHAR(250),
  user_address VARCHAR(250),
  user_city    VARCHAR(50),
  user_state   VARCHAR(5),
  user_country VARCHAR(5),
  user_zip     VARCHAR(10)
)

insert into b_user (
  user_id,
  user_name,
  user_email,
  user_address,
  user_city,
  user_state,
  user_country,
  user_zip
) values (
  1,
  'Alice',
  'alice@example.com',
  'A house',
  'A city',
  'STATE',
  'ABC',
  'ZZ0123'
);

insert into b_user (user_id,
                    user_name,
                    user_email,
                    user_address,
                    user_city,
                    user_state,
                    user_country,
                    user_zip)
values (
   (select max(user_id)  from b_user),
   'david brown',
   'david@david.com',
   'david''s house',
   'chicago',
   'il',
   'usa',
   60007
)
```

[db fiddle screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cajtQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Define the column as an `identity` column:

```
CREATE TABLE b_user (
  user_id      INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
  user_name    VARCHAR(250),
  user_email   VARCHAR(250),
  user_address VARCHAR(250),
  user_city    VARCHAR(50),
  user_state   VARCHAR(5),
  user_country VARCHAR(5),
  user_zip     VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Then remove it from the `INSERT`.  It gets assigned a value automatically.

EDIT:

If you cannot modify the table, you can try:

```
values (
   (select coalesce(max(user_id) + 1, 1)  from b_user),
   'david brown',
   'david@david.com',
   'david''s house',
   'chicago',
   'il',
   'usa',
   60007
)
```

This is not thread-safe and is not recommended.  That is why `identity` columns are useful.

Comment: Unfortuantely this is our existing db table which doesn't have identity column set it on :( Thats what i am having to trouble to achieve identity column via my query.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a sequence that starts at your max ID. Then you can select next value for the sequence to easily increment.

EDIT: If you need sequence to start with value from table, you can wrap in exec statement [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913634/how-to-set-start-with-of-sequence-to-select-query-result-in-sql-server)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IDSeq  
    START WITH 2  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

Then

```
values (
   (NEXT VALUE FOR IDSeq),
   'david brown',
   'david@david.com',
   'david''s house',
   'chicago',
   'il',
   'usa',
   60007
)
```